# Lower bound on $\log \left( \sum_{i=1}^tx_i \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> I am wondering if there is a known lower bound on $\log \left( \sum_{i=1}^tx_i \right)$ in terms of some function of $\log(x_i), i=1,\cdots,t$?

My attempt:

Let $t=2$, then:

\begin{align*}
\log(x_1+x_2) &= \log x_1\left(1+\frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) \\
&=\log x_1 + \log \left(1+\frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) \\
&\geq \log x_1 + \left( \frac{\frac{x_2}{x_1}}{1+\frac{x_2}{x_1}} \right) \\
&=\log x_1 + \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2}
\end{align*}

So I am wondering if I can get a similar or a better lower bound for a general $t$ i.e. $t>2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log \, (\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}x_i)=\log n+\log \, (\frac 1 n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}x_i)) \geq \log n+  (\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{t} \log x_i))$ by Jensen's inequality.